# Best way to display frequency

Tags: usability, tables, checkboxes, dropdown, data-tables

Do you guys know any other way to represent a list of items that have their own frequency options (Weekly, Monthly, Daily) that you can choose from. 
I was thinking maybe creating like a table and adding 3 checkboxes under every options or creating something similar to segmented control. [Example](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/segmented-controls/)

I was also thinking of adding a dropdown where you can choose between these three options.
What do you think is the best option in my situation?

Comment: It's more appropriate to share visuals other than links

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like the attachment below.

I don't think it makes sense to compare a weekly value with a monthly value. It depends a lot on what kind of data you want to compare and if all Data rows have a Daily, Weekly, and Monthly value.

Sometimes it doesn't make sense to compare Daily values with Monthly or Weekly. But it's important what kind of data you need to compare.
[image]
**Segmented controller or dropdown?**
It depends on the data on how your users are using your platforms.

- If 80% of their time they use only one value, I would use a dropdown.
- If your users' habits are to browse between those 3 intervals I would leave them as a segmented controller.